# sencha touch routing extraparams kitchensink

Tags: extjs, routes, touch, metadata

I am trying to extend the routing in the Sencha Touch Kitchensink app as follows:

My data (in List store) are as follows:

```
{ category: 'fruit', str: 'tomato'},
{ category: 'fruit', str: 'green bean'},
{ category: 'vegetable', str: 'celery'},
{ category: 'vegetable', str: 'sprouts'},
{ category: 'notAVegetable', str: 'ketchup'},
{ category: 'notAVegetable', str: 'prune'}
```

I would like to show only those data selected by a particular category, such as "fruit"

In the Main.js controller, I am trying to do this by grabbing another parameter from the "List" node in the Demos TreeStore

```
routes: {
        'demo/:id/:category': 'showViewById',
        'menu/:id': 'showMenuById'
    },
```

Where the showViewById action adds the extra parameter for use later

```
showViewById: function (id, category) {
    var nav = this.getNav(),
        view = nav.getStore().getNodeById(id);

    console.log('view ' + id);

this.showView(view);
    this.setCurrentDemo(view);
    this.hideSheets();

    // do stuff with category
},
```

I am trying to add and access 'category' as an extraParameter in my Demos.js store in the "List" tree node as follows:

```
{
    text: 'List',
    leaf: true,
    id: 'list',
    extraParams: {
        category: 'fruit'
    }
},
```

A few questions: Can I use an extraParameter to add this attribute to the Store? If so, how can I access it to use for my routing? I thought it would be available as metadata for my Demos store, but have not been able to access it.

Any alternatives short of creating multiple stores (one for "fruit", "vegetable", "notAVegetable," etc.) with filters on them to achieve the same thing?

TIA!